# Does iteration time enhance the security?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

I have created an encrypted partition with `cryptsetup -i`.

Is it right that `-i` is not necessary as brute-force software can bypass the iteration time?

I'm wondering if this is still the case or if it has become easier to do so now.

Answer (score 2):

There is not one valid answer for all cases. You have to compare the involved key spaces:

- the length of the key actually used for disk encryption
- the length of the key used as input for LUKS

A smart (i.e. dangerous) attacker will always use the simpler approach.

If you have a bad password then iterations increase the attacker's effort. But a smart attacker would ignore the iterations if the result of password length and iterations exceeds the disk key size. In that case the disk key would be attacked directly.

If you have a 128-bit disk key and a password with an approximate entropy of 128 bit then iterations are useless. Without looking it up I assume that the current LUKS does not allow keys smaller than 256 bit, though.

Comment: Most options of `cryptsetup` I'm using are default so I should be safe. By the way, how to check the luks disk key size and password entropy?